# Create new column based on next row

Tags: python, r, powershell, csv, dplyr

I have been opening up a .csv file (from MS SQL 2012) in excel, and using formulas.
My data hopped from 300K to 3.5mm rows and can't fit anymore. (cue laughter)

I have been playing around with R, and took a close look at dplyr's mutate.
However, what I need to do seems a step farther than R's awesome data manipulation.

I am adding new columns based off logic operating on next row, sometimes numeric, sometimes strings.

I am a python newb, and have a hunch it may be a better tool than R for this specific task, maybe not.

I looked and searched all over and still have not found examples similar to the problem I face.

I used to drop in this source.csv

```
id,event,eventDate,direction  
id1,apple,1977-06-26 00:00:00.000,positive  
id1,apple,1980-07-01 00:00:00.000,positive  
id1,candy,1980-05-01 00:00:00.000,negative  
id1,apple,1980-11-21 00:00:00.000,positive  
id2,fruit,1980-06-26 00:00:00.000,positive  
id2,cookie,1990-06-26 00:00:00.000,negative  
id2,cavity,1991-07-15 00:00:00.000,negative  
id2,apple,1991-07-16 00:00:00.000,positive  
id2,apple,1997-01-16 00:00:00.000,positive  
id3,cookie,2010-04-20 00:00:00.000,negative  
id4,cookie,2010-04-20 00:00:00.000,negative  
id4,cookie,2010-04-20 00:00:01.000,negative
```

and create this output.csv

```
id,event,eventDate,direction,idEventNumber,nextEvent,daysUntilNextEvent  
id1,apple,1977-06-26 00:00:00.000,positive,1000,negative,1040  
id1,apple,1980-07-01 00:00:00.000,positive,1001,positive,143  
id1,candy,1980-05-01 00:00:00.000,negative,1002,positive,61  
id1,apple,1980-11-21 00:00:00.000,positive,1003,noFurtherEvent,-1  
id2,fruit,1980-06-26 00:00:00.000,positive,1000,negative,3652  
id2,cookie,1990-06-26 00:00:00.000,negative,1001,negative,384  
id2,cavity,1991-07-15 00:00:00.000,negative,1002,positive,1  
id2,apple,1991-07-16 00:00:00.000,positive,1003,positive,2011  
id2,apple,1997-01-16 00:00:00.000,positive,1004,noFurtherEvent,-1  
id3,cookie,2010-04-20 00:00:00.000,negative,1000,noFurtherEvent,-1  
id4,cookie,2010-04-20 00:00:00.000,negative,1000,negative,0  
id4,cookie,2010-04-20 00:00:01.000,negative,1001,noFurtherEvent,-1
```

My new columns would
-number the events (start at 1000, check if next row's id matches, if so, add one, else start over @ 1000)
-copy the next event, if it exists
-count daysUntilNextEvent (math between mssql datetime output, no fractional days, -1 for last event)

How would you tackle the problem?

Thank you for time|thoughts|encouragement|pointers|examples.

**Correction: original output.csv example above included an error, the example has been corrected, but this occurred after many quick responses, hence why their correct questions and comments may now seem out of place.**

Comment: Powershell could do that easy enough. I figure something like (psudocode) `Import-CSV $path | ForEach{add-member calls to $lastline; output $lastline object to pipe;$lastline=$_} | Export-CSV $newpath`

Comment: The `eventDate` values for 2nd and 3rd row seems interchanged. Is this intended?

Comment: I switched the dates of 07 and 05 by accident, however many replies have worked off the above information, so i left their order and corrected the output.csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.4+
DT = fread("input.csv")[, eventDate := as.Date(eventDate)]   ## -(1)

DT[order(id, eventDate),                                     ## -(2)
     `:=`(idEventNumber = seq.int(1000L, length.out=.N), 
          nextEvent = c(tail(direction, -1L), "noFurtherEvent"), 
          daysUntilNextEvent = c(diff(eventDate), -1L)), 
by=id]
```

1.. First, we use `fread` - fast file reader to read in the `csv` and convert `eventDate` from `character` to `Date` format.

2. Then we order by `id, eventDate` so that dates are in increasing order, and on that order, we group by `id`, and add three columns *by reference* - that is, add those columns to `DT` *in-place*.

   - `idEventNumber` - we start from `1000` and continue incrementing it up to a length of `.N` - which is a special variable that holds the number of observations for each group.
   - `nextEvent` - we take all values from `direction` except the first one *for this group*, and add `noFurtherEvent` as the last value.
   - `daysUntilNextEvent` - we take the difference of all `eventDate` values *for this group* and add `-1L` to the last observation.

Note that the input order is preserved, while the number of days are computed in the correct order.

---

Here's the output:

```
#      id  event  eventDate  direction idEventNumber      nextEvent daysUntilNextEvent
#  1: id1  apple 1977-06-26 positive            1000     negative                 1040
#  2: id1  apple 1980-07-01 positive            1002     positive                  143
#  3: id1  candy 1980-05-01 negative            1001     positive                   61
#  4: id1  apple 1980-11-21 positive            1003 noFurtherEvent                 -1
#  5: id2  fruit 1980-06-26 positive            1000     negative                 3652
#  6: id2 cookie 1990-06-26 negative            1001     negative                  384
#  7: id2 cavity 1991-07-15 negative            1002     positive                    1
#  8: id2  apple 1991-07-16 positive            1003     positive                 2011
#  9: id2  apple 1997-01-16 positive            1004 noFurtherEvent                 -1
# 10: id3 cookie 2010-04-20 negative            1000 noFurtherEvent                 -1
# 11: id4 cookie 2010-04-20 negative            1000     negative                    0
# 12: id4 cookie 2010-04-20 negative            1001 noFurtherEvent                 -1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this operation using `dplyr` in `R`. If your data frame is called ana, you can try the following.

```
library(dplyr)

ana %>%
    mutate(group = cumsum(!duplicated(id)),
           eventDate = as.Date(eventDate, format = "%Y-%m-%d"))%>%
    arrange(id, eventDate) %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(num = row_number() + 999,
          nextEvent = lead(direction, default = "noFurtherEvent"),
          daysUntilNextEvent = as.numeric(lead(eventDate) - eventDate),
          daysUntilNextEvent = replace(daysUntilNextEvent, is.na(.), "-1"))

#    id  event  eventDate  direction group  num      nextEvent daysUntilNextEvent
#1  id1  apple 1977-06-26 positive       1 1000     negative                 1040
#2  id1  candy 1980-05-01 negative       1 1001     positive                   61
#3  id1  apple 1980-07-01 positive       1 1002     positive                  143
#4  id1  apple 1980-11-21 positive       1 1003 noFurtherEvent                 -1
#5  id2  fruit 1980-06-26 positive       2 1000     negative                 3652
#6  id2 cookie 1990-06-26 negative       2 1001     negative                  384
#7  id2 cavity 1991-07-15 negative       2 1002     positive                    1
#8  id2  apple 1991-07-16 positive       2 1003     positive                 2011
#9  id2  apple 1997-01-16 positive       2 1004 noFurtherEvent                 -1
#10 id3 cookie 2010-04-20 negative       3 1000 noFurtherEvent                 -1
#11 id4 cookie 2010-04-20 negative       4 1000       negative                  0
#12 id4 cookie 2010-04-20   negative     4 1001 noFurtherEvent                 -1
```

Comment: i think this takes around ~ 2 hrs with 3 million rows, 4 obs

Comment: @ben_says Thank you for your comment. I realised that I can add `replace` in `mutate`. This will definitely speed up the process. But, it won't be as fast as Arun's idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your output sample is not correctly based on your input sample: "id1,apple,1980-07-01" is "positive" in input but "negative" in output. With this in mind here's an example in PowerShell:

```
$sInFile = "infile.csv"
$sOutFile = "outfile.csv"

$cInTable = Import-Csv -Path $sInFile `
    | Sort-Object -Property @("id", "eventDate")
$cOutTable = $cInTable

$oIdCounters = New-Object PSObject

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $cInTable.Count; $i++) {
    if ([Int]$oIdCounters.($cInTable[$i].id) -lt 1000) {
        $oIdCounters | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" `
            -Name $cInTable[$i].id -Value 1000 
    } else {
        $oIdCounters.($cInTable[$i].id) += 1
    }

    $cOutTable[$i] | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" `
        -Name "idEventNumber" -Value $oIdCounters.($cInTable[$i].id)
}

for ($i = $cInTable.Count - 1; $i -ge 0; $i--) {
    if ($cOutTable[$i].idEventNumber -eq $oIdCounters.($cInTable[$i].id)) {
        $sNextEvent = "noFurtherEvent"
        $iDaysUntilNextEvent = -1
    } else {
        $sNextEvent = $cInTable[$i+1].direction
        $iDaysUntilNextEvent = ([DateTime]$cInTable[$i+1].eventDate -`
                                [DateTime]$cInTable[$i].eventDate).Days
    }

    $cOutTable[$i] | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" `
        -Name "nextEvent" -Value $sNextEvent
    $cOutTable[$i] | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" `
        -Name "daysUntilNextEvent" -Value $iDaysUntilNextEvent
}

$cOutTable | Export-Csv -Path $sOutFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I may be misreading you, but nextEvent should list the next row's event direction. input (id1,apple,1980-07-01 00:00:00.000,positive) so output is the same plus the next row (id1,candy,1980-05-01 00:00:00.000,negative data) thus that is why output is positive positive, then positive negative, because the second row positive follows the first row positive, and the third row negative follows the second row positive.

Comment: Yes. `$cInTable[$i+1].direction` is next row's event direction.

Comment: ahh I see what you mean... i didn't intent to mess up the date order... thank you. the source will always be correctly date ordered. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I took a slightly different direction. I stored the last entry in a variable, and then modified it and passed it through  when processing the next entry, and then just catch up with the last entry after the ForEach loop.

```
$Results = @()
$IDCount=1000
$LastLine = $false
Import-CSV $InPath | sort id,eventdate | ForEach{
    If($LastLine -and $LastLine.ID -eq $_.ID){
        Add-Member -InputObject $LastLine -NotePropertyName 'IDEventNumber' -NotePropertyValue $IDCount
        Add-Member -InputObject $LastLine -NotePropertyName 'nextEvent' -NotePropertyValue $_.Direction
        $Results += Add-Member -InputObject $LastLine -NotePropertyName 'daysUntilNextEvent' -NotePropertyValue ([datetime]$_.EventDate - [datetime]$LastLine.EventDate|Select -Expand Days) -PassThru
        $IDCount++
    }ElseIf($LastLine){
        $IDCount=1000
        Add-Member -InputObject $LastLine -NotePropertyName 'IDEventNumber' -NotePropertyValue $IDCount
        Add-Member -InputObject $LastLine -NotePropertyName 'nextEvent' -NotePropertyValue 'NoFurtherEvent'
        $Results += Add-Member -InputObject $LastLine -NotePropertyName 'daysUntilNextEvent' -NotePropertyValue '-1' -PassThru}
    $LastLine = $_}
Add-Member -InputObject $LastLine -NotePropertyName 'IDEventNumber' -NotePropertyValue $IDCount
Add-Member -InputObject $LastLine -NotePropertyName 'nextEvent' -NotePropertyValue 'NoFurtherEvent'
$Results += Add-Member -InputObject $LastLine -NotePropertyName 'daysUntilNextEvent' -NotePropertyValue '-1' -PassThru
$Results | Export-CSV $OutPath -NoTypeInformation
```

Output is:

```
"id","event","eventDate","direction","IDEventNumber","nextEvent","daysUntilNextEvent"
"id1","apple","1977-06-26 00:00:00.000","positive","1000","negative","1040"
"id1","candy","1980-05-01 00:00:00.000","negative","1001","positive","61"
"id1","apple","1980-07-01 00:00:00.000","positive","1002","positive","143"
"id1","apple","1980-11-21 00:00:00.000","positive","1000","NoFurtherEvent","-1"
"id2","fruit","1980-06-26 00:00:00.000","positive","1000","negative","3652"
"id2","cookie","1990-06-26 00:00:00.000","negative","1001","negative","384"
"id2","cavity","1991-07-15 00:00:00.000","negative","1002","positive","1"
"id2","apple","1991-07-16 00:00:00.000","positive","1003","positive","2011"
"id2","apple","1997-01-16 00:00:00.000","positive","1000","NoFurtherEvent","-1"
"id3","cookie","2010-04-20 00:00:00.000","negative","1000","NoFurtherEvent","-1"
"id4","cookie","2010-04-20 00:00:00.000","negative","1000","negative","0"
"id4","cookie","2010-04-20 00:00:01.000","negative","1001","NoFurtherEvent","-1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution in python:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

_data = '''id1,apple,1977-06-26 00:00:00.000,positive
id1,apple,1980-07-01 00:00:00.000,positive
id1,candy,1980-05-01 00:00:00.000,negative
id1,apple,1980-11-21 00:00:00.000,positive
id2,fruit,1980-06-26 00:00:00.000,positive
id2,cookie,1990-06-26 00:00:00.000,negative
id2,cavity,1991-07-15 00:00:00.000,negative
id2,apple,1991-07-16 00:00:00.000,positive
id2,apple,1997-01-16 00:00:00.000,positive
id3,cookie,2010-04-20 00:00:00.000,negative
id4,cookie,2010-04-20 00:00:00.000,negative
id4,cookie,2010-04-20 00:00:01.000,negative'''
```

I first create a dict with `ids` as the keys with a list of items for that id:

```
data = {}
for line in _data.split('\n'):
    fields = line.split(',')
    data.setdefault(fields[0], []).append(fields[1:])
```

I then iterate through this dict in sorted() order to preserve the order of ids. For each id, I create a new list composed of either a pair of rows or a single row. For each id, I initialize it_id to 1000 and increment this for every row printed for this id.

I then iterate through this list. Depending on whether we are working with a pair or a single row, I either calculate the delta or I don't.

```
for item in sorted(data):
    it_id = 1000
    for sub in [data[item][i:i+2] for i in range(len(data[item]))]:
        if len(sub) == 2:
            delta = datetime.strptime(sub[1][1][:-4], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime(sub[0][1][:-4], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            print '%s,%s,%d,%s,%d' % (item, ','.join(sub[0]), it_id, sub[1][2], delta.days)
        it_id += 1
        else:
            print '%s,%s,%d,%s,%d' % (item, ','.join(sub[0]), it_id, 'noFurtherEvent', -1)
```

**Output:**

```
id1,apple,1977-06-26 00:00:00.000,positive,1000,positive,1101
id1,apple,1980-07-01 00:00:00.000,positive,1001,negative,-61
id1,candy,1980-05-01 00:00:00.000,negative,1002,positive,204
id1,apple,1980-11-21 00:00:00.000,positive,1003,noFurtherEvent,-1
id2,fruit,1980-06-26 00:00:00.000,positive,1000,negative,3652
id2,cookie,1990-06-26 00:00:00.000,negative,1001,negative,384
id2,cavity,1991-07-15 00:00:00.000,negative,1002,positive,1
id2,apple,1991-07-16 00:00:00.000,positive,1003,positive,2011
id2,apple,1997-01-16 00:00:00.000,positive,1004,noFurtherEvent,-1
id3,cookie,2010-04-20 00:00:00.000,negative,1000,noFurtherEvent,-1
id4,cookie,2010-04-20 00:00:00.000,negative,1000,negative,0
id4,cookie,2010-04-20 00:00:01.000,negative,1001,noFurtherEvent,-1
```

As another posted suggested, your sample output might be wrong with regard to the deltas.